# How to send ACK with data payload using python

Tags: python, tcp

I am trying to send an ACK with a data payload using the socket library but I cannot understand how to do it.

Is this supported and if not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy). You can forge all the packets you want with it and it's a fairly simple API.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this , Socket library uses high level APIs like :
`bind()`
`listen()`
`accept()` ... etc

the acks will be handled for you ,

Answer (score 0):

As my python script was acting as a TCP server, all I had to do is use the socket.send() method to send the data payload.

This is how it looks in wireshark

[image]

1st line : script/server is receiving the data from client

2nd line : ack from server

3rd line:  script is sending the data payload

4th line:  ack from client

Although this is not a data payload in the 1st ACK, the client treated the reply as a successful one.